# getchar() continues to accept input after including Ctrl+Z in same line

Tags: c, getchar

Simple c program to accept and print the character.

```
int c;
while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
{
  putchar(c);
}
```

I am not getting why it accept input when I press Ctrl+Z at the end of line
ex Hello(press Ctrl+Z)
   hello (some symbol)
but it work properly after leaving a line then pressing Ctrl+Z.
And I am using Window 7

[image: Ouput]

Comment: Are you running this on Windows or some flavour of Unix/Linux?  On my Mac and most Unixes, Ctrl-Z suspends the process.

Comment: What generates EOF is platform dependent. If you are on *nix systems, use `CTRL+D`. `CTRL+Z` works on Windows.

Comment: AFAIK, on Windows you also have to hit enter along with EOF (CTRL + Z).

Comment: This part "*... at the end of line ex Hello(press Ctrl+Z) hello (some symbol) but  ...*" of your question is not completely clear to me. Please be more clear/precise with you want to express.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking, please clearify you question.

Comment: Could you  please format carefully your input? Do it similary to how you formatted the source code (that is, separate with an empty line and indent with 4 spaces), so we could understand precisely what characters you typed as your program input. Don't forget to mark newlines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `getchar()` it in turn ends up making a `read()` system call.  The `read()` will block until it has some characters available.  The terminal driver only makes characters available when you press the return key or the key signifying end of input.  At least that is what it looks like.  In reality, it's more involved.

On the assumption that by ctrl-Z you mean whatever keystroke combination means "end of input", the reason is the way that the `read()` system call works.  The ctrl-D (it's ctrl-D on most Unixes) character doesn't mean "end of input", it means "send the current pending input to the application".

When you've typed something in before pressing ctrl-D, that input gets sent to the application which is probably blocked on the `read()` system call.  `read()` fills a buffer with the input and returns the number of bytes it put in the buffer.

When you press ctrl-D without any input pending (i.e. the last thing you didwas hit `return` or ctrl-D, the same thing happens but there are no characters, so `read()` returns 0.  `read()` returning 0 is the convention for end of input.  When `getchar()` sees this, it returns `EOF` to the calling program.

This answer in Stack Exchange puts it a bit more clearly

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/177662/6555

Answer (score 1):

You have not said what system you are working on, [U|Li]nix or Windows.  This answer is Windows specific.  For [Li|U]nix, replace references to ctrl-z with ctrl-d.

While using a terminal, Ctrl-z will not produce an EOF (-1) (see good answers from Haccks & JeremyP for detailed whys), so the loop will not exit the way you have it written.  However, you can put a test for ctrl-z in your while loop condition to exit...

```
int main ()
{
    int c=0;

    puts ("Enter text. ctrl-z to exit:");

    while(c != 26) //(26 is the ASCII value for ctrl-z)
    {
        putchar(c);
        c = getchar();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

By the way, ***[here is a table showing the values for ASCII control characters.](http://www.robelle.com/smugbook/ascii.html)***

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: "*Ctrl-z is not == EOF*": On windows it is.

Comment: @haccks -  What else would you suggest I say?

Comment: @ryyker; I am surprised that what OP is saying is happening to my test program too. Looking for the valid reason.

Comment: @alk - Not always.  On Windows, in a command prompt it is not.  (Nor is it in Linux).  OP did not specify which system.  I addressed question from perspective of OPs given information - which includes using a command prompt, and using Windows command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file):

> **In Microsoft's DOS and Windows** (and in CP/M and many DEC operating systems), **reading from the terminal will never produce an `EOF`**. Instead, programs recognize that the source is a terminal (or other "character device") and interpret a given reserved character or sequence as an end-of-file indicator; most commonly this is an ASCII Control-Z, **code 26**.

Comment: Hmmm: Disagree.  Compiled `int main(void) { int c; do { c = getchar(); printf("%d\n", c); fflush(stdout); } while (c != EOF); return 0; }` with GCC version 4.9.2, ran in a Windows 'cmd' shell, typed Crtrl-Z and the output was `-1` and program completion.

Comment: Now give input as: `abcdCtrl+Z` and tell me what happened.

Comment: `abcdCtrl+Z` (with no enter) --> `-1` and program completion, no 97,98,99,100.  Just the `EOF`.

Comment: On my system It prints `97\n98\n99\n100\n26` and program waiting for next input.

Comment: Perhaps it depends on the compiler and not the OS?

Comment: I know this is old, but I ran into a similar (possibly related) phenomena that may explain.  In the environment I use, I can explicitly choose whether the build targets a `console` application.  The _console_ behavior appears to change based on this setting.  In particular, the behavior of `stdin` and `stdout` are modified based on that setting.  For example, as a console application, I can capture any `printf()` output by piping it through `stdout` to the parent process.  If I build without specifying _console_, `printf()` calls are not captured.  This may explain different ctrl-Z behavior.

Answer (score -1):

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 int main()
  {  
     int  c;
     while((c=getchar())!=26)
      {
           putchar(c);
      }
  }
```

You can use `ASCII` value of `CTRL-Z`.Now it won't take input after pressing `CTRL-Z`.

Comment: int is what ***[getchar()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/getchar/)*** returns.  What is wrong with that?

Comment: int is needed for getchar as EOF must be outside of char's (byte) range

Comment: In fact declaring c as a char and expecting the code to still work properly used to be an often asked question on SO

Comment: @ryyker Please see the edit .Pervious I made a mistake .

Comment: @ryyker  I didn't asked  to remove  downvote  ,I just wanted to inform that i corrected my mistake .

Answer (score -1):

getchar() fution read single character  by  Pressing Ctrl+Z sends the TSTP signal to your process, means terminate the process (unix/linux)

Comment: Stopping a process is different from ending/terminating a process. A stopped process may be continued again, a terminated process may not. For your reference: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html